# Phaser JS - Uncaught TypeError: this.onTextureUpdate is not a function

Tags: javascript, debugging, phaser-framework

In some code I'm writing, I've made a class called Skeleton, that extends Entity that extends GameObject that extends Phaser.Sprite. I have also made a player class. But the player class code works fine. Though now that I have added a skeleton, it throws the error: `Uncaught TypeError: this.onTextureUpdate is not a function` (The error is in the phaser file) But the player code is more or less the same as skeleton (Only difference is that player inherits from entity, not enemy)

Here is player code:

```
var Player = function(game, x, y, stats) {
    Entity.call(this, game, x, y, 'player', 1, 24, 14, 26, stats, [
        [0, 1],
        [2, 3],
        [4, 5],
        [6, 7]
    ], [
        [8, 9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14, 15],
        [16, 17, 18, 19],
        [20, 21, 22, 23]
    ], 10, 10);

    this.width = 30;
    this.height = 40;
};

Player.prototype = Object.create(Entity.prototype);
Player.prototype.constructor = Player;

Player.prototype.update = function() {
    game.physics.arcade.collide(this, objects, null, function(obj1, obj2) {
        return obj2 instanceof Wall;
    });

    this.moving = false;

    if (cursors.up.isDown) {
        this.direction = Entity.prototype.directions.BACKWARD;
        this.moving = true;

    } else if (cursors.down.isDown) {
        this.direction = Entity.prototype.directions.FORWARDS;
        this.moving = true;
    } else if (cursors.left.isDown) {
        this.direction = Entity.prototype.directions.LEFT;
        this.moving = true;
    } else if (cursors.right.isDown) {
        this.direction = Entity.prototype.directions.RIGHT;
        this.moving = true;
    }

    this.requiredFunctions();
};
```

skeleton:

```
var Skeleton = function(game, x, y, stats) {
    Enemy.call(this, game, x, y, 'skeleton', 1, 23, 13, 5, stats, [
        [0, 1],
        [2, 3],
        [4, 5],
        [6, 7]
    ], [
        [8, 9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14, 15],
        [16, 17, 18, 19],
        [20, 21, 22, 23]
    ], 5, 5, "LEFT_TO_RIGHT_MOVEMENT");
};

Skeleton.prototype = Object.create(Enemy.prototype);
Skeleton.prototype.constructor = Skeleton;
```

GameObject:

```
var GameObject = function(game, x, y, texture, boxX, boxY, boxW, boxH) {
    Phaser.Sprite.call(this, game, x, y, texture);

    game.physics.arcade.enable(this);

    objects.push(this);

    game.math.snapTo(this.x, 32);
    game.math.snapTo(this.y, 32);

    this.body.setSize(boxW, boxH, boxX, boxY);
};

GameObject.prototype = Object.create(Phaser.Sprite.prototype);
GameObject.prototype.constructor = GameObject;

GameObject.prototype.update = function() {
    if(debugMode) {
        this.game.debug.body(this);
    }
}
```

entity:

```
var Entity = function(game, x, y, texture, boxX, boxY, boxW, boxH, stats, idleFrames, movingFrames, idleFrameRate, movingFrameRate) {
    GameObject.call(this, game, x, y, texture, boxX, boxY, boxW, boxH);

    this.stats = stats;

    this.idleFrameRate = idleFrameRate;
    this.movingFrameRate = movingFrameRate;

    this.animations.add("idle forward", idleFrames[0], this.idleFrameRate, true);
    this.animations.add("idle right", idleFrames[1], this.idleFrameRate, true);
    this.animations.add("idle left", idleFrames[2], this.idleFrameRate, true);
    this.animations.add("idle backward", idleFrames[3], this.idleFrameRate, true);

    this.animations.add("moving forward", movingFrames[0], this.movingFrameRate, true);
    this.animations.add("moving right", movingFrames[1], this.movingFrameRate, true);
    this.animations.add("moving left", movingFrames[2], this.movingFrameRate, true);
    this.animations.add("moving backward", movingFrames[3], this.movingFrameRate, true);

    this.animations.play("idle forward");

    this.moving = false;

    //0 = forward
    //1 = right
    //2 = left
    //3 = back
    this.direction = 0;

    this.effects = [];
};

Entity.prototype = Object.create(GameObject.prototype);
Entity.prototype.constructor = Entity;

Entity.prototype.move = function() {
    if(this.moving) {
        switch(this.direction) {
            case Entity.prototype.directions.FORWARDS:
                this.body.velocity.y += this.stats.speed;
                this.direction = 0;
                this.moving = true;
                break;

            case Entity.prototype.directions.BACKWARDS:
                this.body.velocity.y -= this.stats.speed;
                this.direction = 3;
                this.moving = true;
                break;

            case Entity.prototype.directions.RIGHT:
                this.body.velocity.x += this.stats.speed;
                this.direction = 1;
                this.moving = true;
                break;

            case Entity.prototype.directions.LEFT:
                this.body.velocity.x -= this.stats.speed;
                this.direction = 2;
                this.moving = true;
                break;
        }
    }
};

Entity.prototype.requiredFunctions = function() {
    this.physics();
    this.statusEffects();
    this.move();
    this.animate();

    if(debugMode) {
        this.game.debug.spriteBounds(this);
    }
};

Entity.prototype.statusEffects = function() {
    this.stats.resetToDef();

    for (i in this.effects) {
        if (this.effects[i].dead) {
            this.effects.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
};

Entity.prototype.addEffect = function(effect) {
    var name = effect.name.split(" ")[0];
    var p = [];

    for (i in this.effects) {
        if (i.name.split(" ")[0] == name) {
            p.push(i);
        }
    }

    if (p.length === 0) {
        this.effects.push(effect);
    } else {
        var p1 = [];

        var potency = effect.potency;

        for (i in p) {
            if (i.potency > potency) {
                return;
            }

            if (i.potency === potency) {
                p1.push(i);
            }
        }

        if (p1.length === 0) {
            this.effects.push(effect);
        } else {
            var p2 = [];

            var time = effect.effectTime;

            for (i in p1) {
                if (i.effectTime >= time) {
                    return;
                }
            }

            this.effects.push(effect);
        }
    }
};

Entity.prototype.physics = function() {
    this.body.velocity.y = 0;
    this.body.velocity.x = 0;
};

Entity.prototype.animate = function() {
    this.smoothed = false;

    if (!this.moving) {
        switch (this.direction) {
            case 0:
                this.animations.play('idle forward');
                break;
            case 1:
                this.animations.play('idle right');
                break;
            case 2:
                this.animations.play('idle left');
                break;
            case 3:
                this.animations.play('idle backward');
                break;
        }
    } else {
        switch (this.direction) {
            case 0:
                this.animations.play('moving forward');
                break;
            case 1:
                this.animations.play('moving right');
                break;
            case 2:
                this.animations.play('moving left');
                break;
            case 3:
                this.animations.play('moving backward');
                break;
        }
    }
};

Entity.prototype.directions = {
    FORWARD: 0,
    FORWARDS: 0,
    RIGHT: 1,
    LEFT: 2,
    BACKWARD: 3,
    BACKWARDS: 3
};

Entity.prototype.update = function() {
    this.requiredFunctions();
};
```

enemy:

```
var Enemy = function(game, x, y, texture, boxX, boxY, boxW, boxH, stats, idleFrames, movingFrames, idleFrameRate, movingFrameRate, movementType) {
    Entity.call(game, x, y, texture, boxX, boxY, boxW, boxH, stats, idleFrames, movingFrames, idleFrameRate, movingFrameRate);

    this.movementFunc = undefined;

    switch(movementType) {
        case "LEFT_TO_RIGHT_MOVEMENT":
            this.movementFunc = this.LEFT_TO_RIGHT_MOVEMENT;
            break;
        case "UP_TO_DOWN_MOVEMENT":
            this.movementFunc = this.UP_TO_DOWN_MOVEMENT;
            break;
        case "STATIC_MOVEMENT":
            this.movementFunc = this.STATIC_MOVEMENT;
            break;
        default:
            throw "ERROR: Invalid movement type specified for instance of " + this.constructor;
    }
};

Enemy.prototype = Object.create(Entity.prototype);
Enemy.prototype.constructor = Enemy;

Enemy.prototype.move = function() {
    Enemy.move.apply(this);
    movementFunc();
};

Enemy.prototype.STATIC_MOVEMENT = function() {

};

Enemy.prototype.LEFT_TO_RIGHT_MOVEMENT = function() {
    if(this.direction === Entity.directions.FORWARDS || this.direction === Entity.directions.BACKWARDS) {
        this.direction = Entity.directions.RIGHT;
    }

    game.phyics.arcade.collide(this, walls, function(obj1, obj2) {
        this.direction = this.direction === Entity.directions.RIGHT ? Entity.directions.LEFT : Entity.directions.RIGHT;
    });
};

Enemy.prototype.UP_TO_DOWN_MOVEMENT = function() {
    if(this.direction === Entity.directions.RIGHT || this.direction === Entity.directions.LEFT) {
        this.direction = Entity.directions.FORWARDS;
    }

    game.phyics.arcade.collide(this, walls, function(obj1, obj2) {
        this.direction = this.direction === Entity.directions.FORWARDS ? Entity.directions.DOWNWARDS : Entity.directions.FORWARDS;
    });
};
```

Please say if you need anymore of the code.

EDIT: I have just realised that I left out this at the start of Enemy.call(), but after doing that, the error still happens though.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do the same for enemy that I did for skeleton! (see edit) sorry!